# Django User Profile - Forms

Tags: python, django, forms, web

**Django 1.4**

Sorry if this is a silly question i am fairly new to Django. 
I am attempting to link a user and a profile together via the inbuilt auth profile system. All the examples of this i can find do not use a class based view, which is something i would really like to use.

Basically i would like a form that combines the Profile and the User allowing me to create both at the same time. If possible i would like to use the same form to Edit/Create the User + Profile.

I have created a model for the profile: **Profile**

Created forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User


class ProfileRegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'profile-register-form.html'
    form_class    = UserForm
    success_url   = '/account/created/'
```

Adding the profile to the user model does not seem to include it within the UserForm:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "creative_profile.Profile"
```

The 2nd alternative i have tried was to define individual forms in forms.py however the form_class attribute only accepts one form model..

Any pointers help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to include the Profile fields in your UserForm and override the [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) method to populate the Profile fields.

The save() method will have to include a [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) call for the Profile model if you're not using a [post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) to create it. If you are using a post_save signal to create the Profile model, you're going to have to make sure the User is being saved first before calling the get_profile() method.

Answer (score 0):

I do it in more simple way (i suggest). Just use django build in. In **urls.py** I added `(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login')`. In **settings.py** add **LOGIN_URL='/login/'** and to **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** add **'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'**. Copy **registration/login.html** template locally if you want to change it. After such manipulations you will have ability to login as user. Forgot, you also should import from **django.contrib.auth.models** User and Group.